# how to implement unique IDs across many tables

Tags: mysql, database, unique, key

If you look at facebook's graph API, it seems as though all objects share the same ID space, and all Ids are unique even if they are in different tables.

Is there a feature in MySQL that handles this? (if not, high level idea of how to implement?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). It returns a globally unique ID so your IDs will never clash.

To convert it to integer format, you can

```
UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''))
```

for storing in a `BINARY(16)` column.

(Source for converting to integer: [Nicholas Sherlock's comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) at MySQL reference)

Comment: it seems to return a string, how does this translate to serial primary keys?

Comment: It's actually a 128-bit integer returned in a string format. Edited my answer to include method to convert that to 16-byte integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single master database server, you can create a table called Object that has an integer auto-incrementing primary key and an object type column.  Every time you create an object, you insert a row into this Object table first, get the id, then use that id to insert a row into whatever table will hold the object information.  So to create an Event:

```
INSERT INTO Object (object_type) VALUES ('Event')
```

Get the last insert id, let's say it's 12345.

```
INSERT INTO Event (id, name, location) VALUES (12345, 'Cookout', 'My back yard')
```

Comment: <sarcasm>That's certainly scalable.</sarcasm>

Comment: so how would you query for an object given it's ID? Iterate through all tables?

Comment: @pyramation Query the object table first to find the type, then query the appropriate table.  Keep the recently queried object types in memcache to avoid extra queries.

Comment: @walrii That's sufficiently scalable for small sites.  Unless you think you'll grow to the size of Facebook or Twitter, this will work just fine.  And if you do grow that big, that's a good problem to have.  Then you can use Twitter's Snowflake: http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html

Answer (score 0):

OR use a single sequence to drive the ID values.